# How to add a style only to one specific column once it's sorted in React Table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I want to add margin-left only to one specific column of the table once its header is clicked.
Right now it works that once I click on in one column header each header in the table gets the same margin. Logic is executed by flag "isSorted". Can You please advise how to achieve the result where margin will be added only to column which is clicked ?

```
  const [isSorted, setIsSorted] = useState(false);

    const RenderDesktopVersion = ({ column, idx }) => {
        return (
            <StyledHeaderWrapperDesktop>
                <StyledTitleAndSortedIconWrapper
                    onClick={() =>
                        !column.isSortedDesc
                            ? setIsSorted('true')
                            : setIsSorted('false')
                    }
                >
                    <span
                        {...column.getHeaderProps(
                            column.getSortByToggleProps(),
                            {
                                className: column.collapse ? 'collapse' : '',
                            }
                        )}
                    >
                        {column.render('Header')}
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        {column.isSorted ? (
                            column.isSortedDesc ? (
                                <StyledArrowDownwardIcon />
                            ) : (
                                <StyledArrowUpwardIcon />
                            )
                        ) : (
                            ''
                        )}
                    </span>
                </StyledTitleAndSortedIconWrapper>
                <span
                    // style={{
                    //     marginLeft: '12px',
                    // }}
                    style={{
                        marginLeft: isSorted ? '12px' : '0px',
                    }}
                >
                    {columnsCount > 5 ? (
                        <StyledHeaderDivFlex>
                            {column.canFilter ? column.render('Filter') : null}
                        </StyledHeaderDivFlex>
                    ) : (
                        <StyledHeaderDivBlock>
                            {column.canFilter ? column.render('Filter') : null}
                        </StyledHeaderDivBlock>
                    )}
                </span>
            </StyledHeaderWrapperDesktop>
        );
    };
```

that's initial look:
[image]

and now margin should be added only to second column as it was clicked, but it's added to all:
[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you could make `isSorted` type `number | null`, call it `sortIndex` and then when adding the margin write: `marginLeft: sortIndex === idx ? '12px' : '0px'`. and then also `OnClick={() => setSortIndex(idx)}`

Comment: I applied Your suggestions, not fully directly, but You shown me the path and I kept the logic. Unfortunately it still works with all columns. I want it to work only when I press on columns with index = 1,2,9,10. Once I press on header of any column from mentioned indexes it adds margin left to all columns instead of the one which was pressed. Do You have any ideas how can I apply it ? Thanks !